# What does "identically distributed" mean?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, definition

When two distributions have the same variance and shape, do we call them identically distributed, regardless of their mean (as this is usually a location parameter)?

Comment: No. $\qquad \qquad$

Comment: @ZacharySelk Then what does it mean by identically distributed?

Comment: The means has to be the same as well.

Comment: What does "shape" mean?

Comment: @bof Some functions $f$ and $g$ have the same shape if there exists $(a,b,c)$ with $a>0$ and $b$ nonzero such that $f(x)=ag(bx+c)$ for every $x$.

Comment: @Did Thanks. And the functions were talking about here are the cumulative distribution functions of random variables, right?

Comment: @bof Maybe. I would rather think of densities. E.g. the clock-shape of a normal distribution.

Comment: @bof Rather the PDFs, but this also works with the CDFs.

Answer (score 25):

Two (real-valued) random variables $X$ and $Y$ are *identically distributed* if
$$
P(X \leq x) = P(Y \leq x)
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: To be precise, I am asking this question because one example in the lecture.  Consider $\Omega = [0,1]$ with $\textbf{P}\sim U[0,1]$. Let $X_n := \textbf{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}]}, X:=\textbf{1}_{[\frac{1}{2},1]} $ show that $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$

Comment: $[0,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}]$ for the first indicator function and $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ for the next.

Comment: @user1292919 If this is what you wanted to ask, the present post is spectacularly inadequate to the task, I am afraid...

Comment: @user1292919 In other words, two variables are identically distributed iff their (cumulative) **distribution** functions are **identical**.  Doesn't the phrase "identically distributed" make a lot of sense now?

Answer (score 24):

We **never** call two distributions identically distributed.

We eventually do call two random variables $X,Y$ identically distributed.

This if they have the same distribution, i.e. if $P_X=P_Y$ where $P_X$ stands for the induced probability prescribed by $A\mapsto P(\{X\in A\})$ on Borel-measurable sets $A$.

A *sufficient* condition for this is $F_X=F_Y$ where $F_X$ denotes the CDF of $X$.

This condition is also necessary since $F_X$ is actually a restriction of $P_X$ to specific Borel-measurable sets. This fact is less interesting, but worth mentioning as the comments on this question show.

Things like mean, variance and shape (I suspect you mean the graph of an eventual PDF) are - if they exist - completely determined by the distribution.

Comment: And the condition $F_X=F_Y$ you mention is both sufficient and necessary, so this answer is "compatible" with Artem Mavrin's answer.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Indeed. $F_X$ is actually a restriction of $P_X$ to specific sets, so necessity speaks for itself. I could make my answer a bit more general by changing "random variables" into "random vectors".

Answer (score 6):

The probability assigned to each event in the set must be the same. In the case that real numbers are the set of outcomes then Artems answer is good, but not all probabilities are assigned to real numbers! For example tossing two identical coins $A,B$ then if

$$\cases{P(A=heads) = P(B=heads)\\P(A=tails) = P(B=tails)}$$

and we know that $\Omega = \{heads,tails\}$ then they are identcally distributed. But neither "heads" or "tails" are real numbers.

Comment: On the other hand, one can always take one's base probability space to be $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: But we need some way to order the elements of the set of our space, don't we? To know where on the interval they show up.

Comment: Not really, that's a lower level view than you should take. The easier way to see that this works is to recall that a random variable $X$ with quantile function $Q_X$ has the same distribution as $Q_X(U)$ where $U$ is $U(0,1)$. Thus given a r.v. on a general probability space, we can construct its quantile function $Q_X$ and then get a r.v. with the same distribution defined on $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure. Indeed this is precisely how most numerical sampling techniques work. (Some, like the Box-Muller algorithm, use a variant on this technique, but all basically work using this idea.)

Comment: Things get impractical when you get to vector-valued r.v.s (where you need a measure-preserving bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]^d$), sequences of r.v.s, function space valued r.v.s, etc. But they still actually work *formally*, to my recollection. It's just that explicitly writing down the mappings can be rather tedious.

Comment: Ah, cool I should probably read up on it. I got stuck in thinking about arithmetic coding where one needs an order for the events or "symbols" as they are called and what is done is to estimate probabilities and then pretend to "sample" using these estimates, writing down the bit-stream of the number on that interval $[0,1]$ as new events occur / symbols arrive. Hmm a bit too long for a comment I guess.

Answer (score 0):

In probability theory and statistics, a sequence or other collection of random variables are *independent and identically distributed* (i.i.d.) if each random variable has the same probability distribution as the others and all are mutually independent.

Comment: So.... what does it mean by the same probability distribution? I was not asking about i.i.d.